# How to convert different json response to dart class from the same endpoint

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter application connected to one WebSocket, and that endpoint returns JSON, and inside the JSON body, there are two fields (**type** & **responseData**). Each time the WebSocket returns JSON with a different **responseData** body.

Example,

**Type one**

```
{
    "type": 1,
    "responseData": [
        {
         "albumId": 1,
         "id": 1,
         "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
         "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952"
        },
    ]
}
```

**Type two**

```
{
    "type": 2,
    "responseData": [
        {
         "name": "test",
         "logoUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952"
        },
    ]
}
```

**Type three**

```
{
    "type": 3,
    "responseData": [
        {
         "name": "test2",
         "price": 23
        },
    ]
}
```

What is the best way to convert these JSON bodies to a dart class based on the different types?

Comment: there are only 3 type of responseData return from web socket ?

Comment: You could setup a base clase for the response, create a factory constructor - as per this example: https://developers.google.com/codelabs/from-java-to-dart#3. Or you can just simply do a simple switch statement (or few if-then statements) and get it done.

Comment: thus those types only limit to 3? if does limit to those types just use if else inside the websocket